# adding resources (xml+mp3+video+images) with swf in itext for creating dynamic pdf (using java)

Tags: xml, flash, itext

I have created one swf file, in which it will run with the help of some external files (5 mp3 files, 2 xml files, and 6 image files). When I have create the pdf using itext I can only able to embedded the swf file alone. How should able to add these external files to run the swf.  It would be helpful if you give some sample. Can you please help me where should i have to add the values for adding the image,mp3 and xml files to run the swf.

My code is below :

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("welcome.pdf"));
writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_7);
writer.addDeveloperExtension(PdfDeveloperExtension.ADOBE_1_7_EXTENSIONLEVEL3);

document.open();


RichMediaAnnotation richMedia = new RichMediaAnnotation(writer, new Rectangle(36, 400, 559,806));

PdfFileSpecification fs  = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(writer, "ballon.swf", "ballon.swf", null);

PdfIndirectReference asset = richMedia.addAsset("ballon.swf", fs);

RichMediaConfiguration configuration = new RichMediaConfiguration(PdfName.FLASH);
RichMediaInstance instance = new RichMediaInstance(PdfName.FLASH);
RichMediaParams flashVars = new RichMediaParams();
String vars = new String("&day=2011-10-13");
flashVars.setFlashVars(vars);
instance.setParams(flashVars);
instance.setAsset(asset);
configuration.addInstance(instance);

PdfIndirectReference configurationRef = richMedia.addConfiguration(configuration);

RichMediaActivation activation = new RichMediaActivation();
activation.setConfiguration(configurationRef);
richMedia.setActivation(activation);

PdfAnnotation richMediaAnnotation = richMedia.createAnnotation();
richMediaAnnotation.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
writer.addAnnotation(richMediaAnnotation);

document.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You add those resources using the same method (AddAsset):

PdfIndirectReference resasset = richMedia.AddAsset(...fill in here I am not writing your code...);

You must remember that likely you will need to ensure all contain immediate local references from the XML to the assets for those files, no directory paths (i.e. they are all in the same directory in the working sample you have).

Comment: hi, i have tried but this addAsset is not working for me. Is it possible to give some example.